# get location from response.headers in python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib, response-headers

I am using python `requests` and doing a `post`

```
import requests  
response = requests.post('https://petdogs.net/search/?input=abcdefgh', 
headers=HEADERS, 
allow_redirects=False)

print(response.headers)
```

These are the values in `response` header that I can see in developer tools in browser and I want to get the value for `location`

```
content-language: en-gb
content-length: 0
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Wed, 07 Jul 2021 17:44:52 GMT
location: /product/id=12345/
server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
vary: Accept-Language, Cookie, Origin
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: DENY
```

but when I do `print(response.headers)` I see only this

```
{'Server': 'nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)', 'Date': 'Wed, 07 Jul 2021 18:23:45 GMT',
'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive',
 'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY', 'Vary': 'Accept-Language, Origin', 
'Content-Language': 'en', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}
```

and  `location` is missing

I saw a few answers that talked about

```
'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Location'
```

but I do not know if it is correct and/or how to use it correctly.

I have also tried using `urllib`

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
>>> f = urllib2.urlopen('https://petdogs.net/search/?input=abcdefgh')
>>> print(f.headers)
```

but this responds with

```
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Thu, 08 Jul 2021 11:12:58 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 128053
Connection: close
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Vary: Cookie, Accept-Language, Origin
Content-Language: en
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=xxxxxx; expires=Thu, 07 Jul 2022 11:12:57 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
Set-Cookie: sessionid=bbbbbb; expires=Thu, 22 Jul 2021 11:12:57 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
```

How do I get the value for  `location`?

Comment: does it help if you set the request to `allow_redirects=False`? as in `response = requests.post('https://petdogs.net/search/?input=abcdefgh', headers=HEADERS, allow_redirects=False)`

Comment: @AlmogAtNailo it does not make a difference. I still get the same response. 
```{'Server': 'nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)', 'Date': 'Thu, 08 Jul 2021 11:51:23 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY', 'Vary': 'Accept-Language, Origin', 'Content-Language': 'en', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}```

Answer (score 6):

The solution is simple.
This "location" response header is a rediction.
And the python request module is trying to make things more easy
so it tries to automatically redicit you.
So you can just add the "allow_redirects" parameter and set it to False.

(The request method shouldn't matter)

Example:

```
import requests

res = requests.get("example.com", allow_redirects=False)
print(res.headers)
```

Output:

```
{'Content-Length': '0', 'location': 'your stuff here'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using urllib, its straight forward.[image]

```
from urllib import request, parse

def create_post():
    payload = {'title':'Pyton Requests','body':'Requests are qwesome','userId':1}
    data = parse.urlencode(payload).encode()
    response = request.Request('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', data) 
    resp = request.urlopen(response)
    print(resp.headers['Location'])


def main():
    # """ Main entry point of the app """
    # print("hello world")
    create_post()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """ This is executed when run from the command line """
    main()
```

Comment: ```from urllib import request, parse```
```response = request.Request('https://petdogs.net/search/?input=abcdefgh')```
```resp = request.urlopen(response)```
```print(resp.headers['location'])```


when I do this I get output as ```None```

Comment: could you look at the above? @Vivek

Comment: @raj247, could you please share the actual url, I could not find this petdos url working.